# Top 3 nearest stores

Tags: nearest-neighbor

am a lurker in this website thanks to you all, i manage to find answers and it greatly help me a lot.

Recently i am working on this formula, which gives me the nearest store and distance.

I am using this to find the nearest distance for column F
=ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-E5))*COS(RADIANS(90-G5))+SIN(RADIANS(90-E5))*SIN(RADIANS(90-G5))*COS(RADIANS(F5-H5)))*6371

I am also using this to find the name of the store which is at my the other tab for column D, E and G
=LOOKUP(1,1/FREQUENCY(0,MMULT(('7E LatLong'!$C$2:$D$650-B2:C2)^2,{1;1})),'7E LatLong'!$B$2:$B$650)

My qns is, can i expand it to find the nearest 3 stores name? and their distance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jzAo.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Is this Excel?